# How to import latest Ignite Scheduler repository

Tags: maven, schedule, ignite

I would like to import the Scheduler repository in my project, and I have add the dependency in pom as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-schedule</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But it reports error to load it.

Anyone can help me out, much appreciate for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

ignite-schedule is optional LGPL dependency and it's not published to apache maven repo.

You can build it by yourself from code or use GridGain maven repository to get it.

Here is information about it:
https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#3rdparty

Comment: Already tried to reimport the dependencies in IntelliJ, but still with no luck. It seems that ignite-schedule is not published to public Repository: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Comment: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-schedule/, no 2.1.0 for ignite-schedule

Comment: Updated answer, it should help